# Static variable vs static member

Tags: c++

I saw this at work, and it is written by people before I joined. A static variable is used instead of static member of the class. As for now, I don't see a reason why static member of the class should not be used here. If I want to persuade people here to change it, is there any good excuse to convince them?

I tried to find the difference between static member and static variable, seems like people are leaning toward static member shall always be used unless there is a good reason, but not very real life cases were mentioned.

**Current code:**

```
class Foo {
public:

   static Foo *get() {
       static Foo _instance;

       return &_instance;
   }
// ...
};
```

How this function is being used:

```
int XXX_loadxxx(const char xxx, foo_handle *handle) {
  // just get foo ptr and return

  xxx::foo *ptr = xxx::foo::get();
  int ret = ptr->init();

  if (ret != 0) {
      return -1;
  }
  *handle = ptr;
  return 0;
}
```

Code in my mind how the class should be defined:

```
class Foo {
   static Foo _instance;
public:
      static Foo *get() {
         return &_instance;
      }
// ...
};
```

I'd really appreciate if someone can tell me whether it makes any different to change it to static member, and why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both samples cannot be compiled. What does the `static Foo_instance` mean? Did you mean `static Foo instance`?

Now back to your question: if you define the static variable inside of a function, it will be initialized only when you call the function for the first time. That has 2 consequences:

- You will not spend resources if you never use this object;
- If the constructor requires other resources to be allocated, you may need to control the time of creation. The time of creation of the static member is not defined.

Comment: Please forgive me as a newbee in C++, "The time of creation of the static member is not defined." Does it mean after the class is initialized, its static member still may not exist?

Comment: I might made a mistake and deleted the space between foo and _instance...

Comment: @Johnzy that means the opposite: the static member is allocated and initialized even before any instance of the class is constructed. There is one guarantee though: all static members are initialized before the `main()` function is started. But the order of static members initialization is not defined.

Answer (score 6):

The first solution is better for two reasons:

- the static singleton is initialized the first time `get()` is called, which means you have a predictable behavior, which is not the case with `static` variables on different translation units
- the variable is local so it's only visible from the getter of the singleton, which is usually what you want

I don't see why you would prefer to de-encapsulate it from the method.

Comment: Well, I'm not too familar with these singleton definition, that's why I'm trying to get much info as possible. I just think that the way I suggested will make it (at least looks like) easier to be understood by a newbee like me.

Answer (score 2):

The static member variable (as well as static variables in namespace scope) has a few disadvantages compared to a static local variable:

- It must be defined in a single translation unit. This is not an option for libraries that desire to be "header only". This limitation no longer exists in C++17, which introduced inline variables.
- The order of initialisation of static objects defined in different translation units is undefined. This often leads to undefined behaviour when static objects depend on other static objects, and may get initialised in the wrong order. This problem is called "Static Initialization Order Fiasco". The function local static (mostly<sup>1</sup>) solves this problem, since it is instead initialised on first use. As such, this idiom is called "Construct On First Use".

<sub><sup>1</sup> There is still a convoluted way of violating the ordering guarantees even with Construction On First Use: If there is static object A, whose constructor does not depend on static object B, but the destructor of A does depend on B, then B may still be destroyed first resulting in UB. This can be avoided by always calling the static getter of B in the constructor of A if any part of the A depends on B. In general, static objects should be avoided because of these problems.</sub>

---

P.S. Typically, you'd want to return a reference from the getter, so that the caller doesn't need to worry about getting null.

P.P.S. `static Foo_instance;` should probably be `static Foo instance;`

P.P.P.S. With the static member, the getter becomes mostly<sup>2</sup> useless; the member could instead be made public.

<sub><sup>2</sup> It may still have some value if you intend to use inheritance, to extend the static object while maintaining compatibility with the original interface.</sub>

Comment: 1) "Typically, you'd want to return a reference from the getter, so that the caller doesn't need to worry about getting null." isn't there still a chance that you can get a NULL pointer with the getter function? Otherwise you don't need the code " if (ret != 0) {
      return -1;
  }"

Comment: 3) well, it is true that it will make the getter useless, but if people don't see this part and just use this as a library, they wouldn't know. What would happen if we just make the instance accessable to public? Would it be a real bad thing for a singleton?

Comment: I mean, in this case, it is a singleton(so far it looks like one), and it does not interfere with other classes, so just for this case, would it be a bad thing to make it a public member?

Comment: 2) I saw that I might accidently deleted the space in between foo and _instance... Now it makes more sense, thanks to @Jarod42

Answer (score 0):

The local static varaible initialization is safe in a concurrent environment.

Another advantage is that it is initialized onlt in the case when the corresponding function is called. That is the variable is innitialized by a request.

From the C++ 17 Standard

> 4 Dynamic initialization of a block-scope variable with static storage
>   duration (6.6.4.1) or thread storage duration (6.6.4.2) is performed
>   the first time control passes through its declaration; such a variable
>   is considered initialized upon the completion of its initialization.
>   If the initialization exits by throwing an exception, the
>   initialization is not complete, so it will be tried again the next
>   time control enters the declaration. **If control enters the
>   declaration concurrently while the variable is being initialized, the
>   concurrent execution shall wait for completion of the
>   initialization.** If control re-enters the declaration recursively
>   while the variable is being initialized, the behavior is undefined

Comment: Note that block scope variables weren't thread safe prior to C++11, which may be relevant to people who have to deal with ancient code bases.

Comment: forgive my poor understanding here, can you explain a little bit more on this sentense? "If control enters the declaration concurrently while the variable is being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for completion of the initialization. If control re-enters the declaration recursively while the variable is being initialized, the behavior is undefined"